# Is it possible to have two backgrounds on same element one on top of each other?

Tags: css, background-image

Sometimes the body is smaller than the screen and the background get's cropped. That's why I want to put the two backgrounds in the `<html>` element. I know that with CSS3 it is possible to have one element with two backgrounds (one following the other), written like this:

```
background: url('/images/mosaic.gif') no-repeat, url('/images/photo.png') no-repeat;
```

My question is, is it possible to have 2 images on top of each other? A mosaic repeated and above it a photo no-repeat. I've tried to do it this way, which doesn't work:

```
background: url('/images/mosaic.gif') repeat, url('/images/photo.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and exactly the way you wrote.  [See here for an illustration.](http://jsfiddle.net/qavPg/2/)

```
<div id='cont'></div>​

#cont { 
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/) center center no-repeat,
        url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/) repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a image in top and use color in the bottom like this:

```
background:  URL(images/page_bg.jpg) top left repeat-x #7C8FF7;
```